# Does TaskScheduler.Default not always guarantee the task will be executed on a pool thread?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

Does `TaskScheduler.Default` **not** always guarantee the task will be executed on a pool thread?

While fixing a bug, I found at least one case when it doesn't. It can be reproduced like this (a contrived example made from real code):

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;
sc.Post(_ => tcs.SetResult(true), null);
await tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        // breaks here
        Debug.Assert(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
    }, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Are there any other cases?

Also, is there an elegant way to make sure the `ContinueWith` action is executed synchronously, if the antecedent task has completed on a pool thread, or gets queued to thread pool otherwise (I know I can use `QueueUserWorkItem` in `ContinueWith` action, but I don't like it).

EDITED, I guess I can implement my own `TaskScheduler` and check if I am already on a thread pool thread inside `TryExecuteTaskInline`, to control this.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "... `ContinueWith` action is executed synchronously, if the antecedent task has completed on a pool thread"? What is *synchronously* supposed to mean here? How could it be meaningful if the antecedent ran on a pool thread?

Comment: Also, you say that this repro case doesn't execute on a pool thread, but then what thread *does* it execute on? Is this code snippet part of the UI code in which the current synchronization context is the Winforms or WPF dispatcher? `TaskScheduler` and `SynchronizationContext` have quirky interactions, that's why you normally use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` and not `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: @Aaronaught, the actual code wraps a 3rd party code event with `TaskCompletionSource`. The event can be fired on any thread, including one with synchronization context. I don't want `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` by all means. I want to handle the completion of `TaskCompletionSource.Task` on thread pool. I want to use `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` as optimization if it is already on thread pool, to avoid unneeded thread switch.

Comment: Note, that ExecuteSynchronously is *never* guaranteed to run synchronously on the same thread. It is a hint.

Comment: @usr, thanks for the good point. I just read about when it is not: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/07/10265067.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason this happens is because you use the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`. From the doco:

> ExecuteSynchronously  Specifies that the continuation task should be
>   executed synchronously. With this option specified, the continuation
>   will be run on the same thread that causes the antecedent task to
>   transition into its final state. If the antecedent is already complete
>   when the continuation is created, the continuation will run on the
>   thread creating the continuation. Only very short-running
>   continuations should be executed synchronously.

If the antecedent task completes on a thread other than a thread pool thread then the continuation will run on that thread also. So I guess in that case no scheduling occurs. Another case might be when the continuation task is already complete, which will also run synchronously.

**Update**

To achieve what you are asking in your second part of the question I think you'll need a custom awaiter. See [this articl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx)e for more details but something like this might work for you:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ThreadPoolTaskAwaiter WithThreadPool(this Task task)
    {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskAwaiter(task);
    }

    public class ThreadPoolTaskAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        private readonly TaskAwaiter m_awaiter;

        public ThreadPoolTaskAwaiter(Task task)
        {
            if (task == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("task");
            m_awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();
        }

        public ThreadPoolTaskAwaiter GetAwaiter() { return this; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get { return m_awaiter.IsCompleted; } }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
            {
                continuation();
            }
            else
            {
                Task.Run(continuation);
            }                
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {
            m_awaiter.GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
public static async Task Execute()
{          
    await Task.Delay(500).WithThreadPool();

    // does not break here
    if (!Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` is the reason, but I'm still looking for an answer to the question in the last paragraph of my post.

Comment: I guess I can implement my own TaskScheduler and check if I am already on a thread pool thread inside TryExecuteTaskInline, to control this.

Comment: You might be able to use a custom awaiter as well. See my update.